# phpMyAdmin AuthType=config: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

When I attempt to load phpMyAdmin 4.8.0 using AuthType=config I get an error:

> Cannot connect: invalid settings.
>   mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
>   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the 
>   connection. You should check the host, username and password in your
>   configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by 
>   the administrator of the MySQL server.

The phpMyAdmin config.inc.cfg contains:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'MYUSER';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MYPASSWORD';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql57.sock';
```

I can connect to mysql via commandline using socket with same credentials and /tmp/mysql57.sock exists
Also:

```
ps -edf | grep mysql
```

> mysql    18090 17814  0 20:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/mysql57/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/usr/local/mysql57/my.cnf --basedir=/usr/local/mysql57 --datadir= mysqldata/mysql57 --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql57/lib/plugin --log-error=myhost.com.err --pid-file=myhost.com.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql57.sock --port=3306

I have skip-networking in my.cnf so cannot use 127.0.0.1 for host. What can be the problem?

More Details:

Centos 7.4

mysql-5.7.21-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64 (generic binary), community version

PHP 7.2.4

nginx-1.12.2

Comment: What Linux distribution? What MySQL version? Where did you get it? What PHP version? What web server? And include any other details that might be relevant.

Comment: I added these details to the bottom of the question. I downloaded MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ I can connect using --host localhost -S /tmp/mysql57.sock on commandline. I also have socket defined in 2 places in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `PrivateTmp` directive is set to `yes` in the service responsible for PHP runtime, thus defining a separate `/tmp` directory and preventing PHP from connecting to `/tmp/mysql57.sock` socket located in system's temporary directory.

There are two possible solutions, which should be applied by extending either `nginx.service` or `php-fpm.service` unit. It depends on how nginx is configured to run PHP scripts.

- Option 1: figure out what systemd unit should be extended and set `PrivateTmp=no` there.
- Option 2: configure MySQL to listen to a UNIX socket in another directory located outside `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`. I suggest you to use either `/run/mysqld.socket` or `/run/mysqld/mysqld.socket` for that.

---

Reference from [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) manual page:

> PrivateTmp=
>
> Takes a boolean argument. If `true`, sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts private `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` directories inside it that is not shared by processes outside of the namespace. This is useful to secure access to temporary files of the process, but makes sharing between processes via `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` impossible. If this is enabled, all temporary files created by a service in these directories will be removed after the service is stopped. Defaults to false. It is possible to run two or more units within the same private `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` namespace by using the `JoinsNamespaceOf=` directive, see `systemd.unit(5)` for details. This setting is implied if `DynamicUser=` is set. For this setting the same restrictions regarding mount propagation and privileges apply as for `ReadOnlyPaths=` and related calls, see above. Enabling this setting has the side effect of adding `Requires=` and `After=` dependencies on all mount units necessary to access `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`. Moreover an implicitly `After=` ordering on `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service(8)` is added.
>
> Note that the implementation of this setting might be impossible (for example if mount namespaces are not available), and the unit should be written in a way that does not solely rely on this setting for security.
>
> This option is only available for system services and is not supported for services running in per-user instances of the service manager.

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using SELinux, check this out.

I had the same problem. I was running CentOS 8 with SELinux enforcing, and I was getting the error mentioned in the question (`mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory`) despite having all the configurations fixed correctly. I later got out of trouble after allowing MySQL connections through SELinux.

Check SELinux status using this command:

```sh
sestatus
```

Allow Apache to connect database through SELinux

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Use `-P` option makes the change permanent. Without this option, the boolean would be reset to 0 at reboot.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For This error you have to restart the service of mysql or which sql you have.
**Service mysql restart**

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself
for this error do this

In the wp-config.php file, include (or change) this line from

```
define(‘DB_HOST’, ‘localhost’);
```

to

```
define(‘DB_HOST’, ‘127.0.0.1’);
```